# Retrieve an API response with Laravel and Guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I want to get the answer from an API in my Laravel project. Obviously Guzzle seems to be the best solution.
This is the Check_MK API in version 1.6.0b6

I created a model to communicate with the API to respect the MVC model

**Model**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

class Hostgroup
{
    public static function all() {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = new Request('GET', 'https://my-api-uri.tld', [
            'query' => [
                'action' => 'get_all_host',
                '_username' => 'user',
                '_secret' => 'secret',
                'output_format' => 'json'
            ]]);
        $hostgroup = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2]);
        return $hostgroup;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Hostgroup;

class MainDashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {
        $hostgroup = Hostgroup::all();
        return view('dashboard.main', [
            'hostgroup' => $hostgroup
        ]);
  }
}
```

Currently I get an error 500 on my project page but the API sends me a code 200 with the header of the request.

Actually i got this:

```
Response {#209 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:9 [▶]
  -headerNames: array:9 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#207 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @278 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$hostgroup` is a `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` which you probably dont want. You'll want the actualy contents of the reponse. Try adding this instead:

```
return $hostgroup->getBody()->getContents();
```

Answer (score -1):

First, I need you to call Guzzle as follow:
Replace :

```
$request = new Request('GET', 'https://my-api-uri.tld', [
```

With:

```
$request = $client->get('https://my-api-uri.tld', [
```

and debug the response comming from function ALL 
make

```
dd($hostgroup);
```

and check the result and compare what is comming from API.
and Also no need to use thoese:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
```